# How can I ensure my clients will get prints from me, without watermarks?

Tags: digital, prints, business

I give my clients their full edited images on CD. How can I ensure that they will print with me and not go elsewhere?

Comment: Depends on your client; voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: I don't see how this question can have a useful answer, as in one that can generally be helpful to others. How any given client will react varies by the client, your business model and pricing, the quality of your work, the genre.

Comment: Huh? "Print with me" makes no sense here.

Comment: I'm not sure that it warrants a downvote, maybe an edit? I think it's a valid question. I've tried to make my answer non subjective and non opinion based

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been downvoted, but I think it deserves an answer.

> how sure am I they will print with me

Not at all. By giving high resolution images without watermarks, you are forfeiting any control method that you might otherwise have been able to use. People will therefore go with what they see as cheapest/best value.

Some people will go for cheap, some will go for better quality. The issue with this is that it's their interpretation of quality/value for money, and not yours.

Comment: It may, however, be possible to influence their perception of quality printing, though marketing your brand to include an expectation or guarantee of quality prints.